# Weird execution time of bottom-up merge sort

Tags: c++, mergesort

I have some ongoing project in which I need to use bottom-up merge sort.
While working on it, I've noticed something strange.

So, here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;

void populateByRandom(int arr[], int n);
void resetArray(int arr[], int n);
void merge1(int arr[], int l, int m, int r);
void mergeSort1(int arr[], int n);
int min(int x, int y);

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    ofstream myfile ("AdvancedSortsTest.txt");
    int n;
    int exponent[3]={13, 17, 21};
    int *arr;
    for(int i=0; i<1; i++)
    {
        n=(2 << exponent[i]);
        arr=new int[n];
        myfile << "For array of size\t" << n << ":" << endl << endl;
        for(int j=0; j<1000; j++)
        {
//          resetArray(arr, n);
            populateByRandom(arr, n);
            auto start=Clock::now();
            mergeSort1(arr, n);
            auto end=Clock::now();
            myfile << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end-start).count() << endl;
        }
        myfile << endl << endl;
        delete [] arr;
    }
    myfile << endl << "*(time in microseconds)";
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}

/* Iterative mergeSort1 function to sort arr[0...n-1] */
void mergeSort1(int *arr, int n)
{
    int curr_size;  // For current size of subarrays to be merged
    // curr_size varies from 1 to n/2
    int left_start; // For picking starting index of left subarray
    // to be merged

    // Merge subarrays in bottom up manner.  First merge subarrays of
    // size 1 to create sorted subarrays of size 2, then merge subarrays
    // of size 2 to create sorted subarrays of size 4, and so on.
    for (curr_size=1; curr_size<=n-1; curr_size = 2*curr_size)
    {
        // Pick starting point of different subarrays of current size
        for (left_start=0; left_start<n-1; left_start += 2*curr_size)
        {
            // Find ending point of left subarray. mid+1 is starting
            // point of right
            int mid = left_start + curr_size - 1;

            int right_end = min(left_start + 2*curr_size - 1, n-1);

            // Merge Subarrays arr[left_start...mid] & arr[mid+1...right_end]
            merge1(arr, left_start, mid, right_end);
        }
    }
}

/* Function to merge the two haves arr[l..m] and arr[m+1..r] of array arr[] */
void merge1(int *arr, int l, int m, int r)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 =  r - m;
    /* create temp arrays */
    int *L=new int[n1];
    int *R=new int[n2];
    /* Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] */
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        L[i] = arr[l + i];
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        R[j] = arr[m + 1+ j];

    /* Merge the temp arrays back into arr[l..r]*/
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = l;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
        if (L[i] <= R[j])
        {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy the remaining elements of L[], if there are any */
    while (i < n1)
    {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy the remaining elements of R[], if there are any */
    while (j < n2)
    {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    delete [] L;
    delete [] R;
}

// Utility function to find minimum of two integers
int min(int x, int y)
{
    return (x<y)? x :y;
}


void populateByRandom(int arr[], int n)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i += 1)
        arr[i]=rand()%1000000;
}
void resetArray(int arr[], int n)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i += 1)
        arr[i]=0;
}
```

Now, here are some sample results:

For array of size   16384:

```
14935
9303
8525
7568
6316
7366
6263
5902
5752
5589
5364
5485
5121
5108
5214
4870
4759
4760
4625
4454
4479
4545
4272
4254
4211
4151
4062
3957
4062
3875
3819
3824
3803
3693
3729
3621
3649
3594
3558
3458
3463
3635
3085
3074
3109
3101
3425
3140
3092
3079
3098
3350
3075
3069
3077
3066
3259
3168
3090
3129
3097
3341
3161
3243
3132
3183
3394
3181
3152
3183
3172
3423
3179
3172
3132
3284
3151
3167
3191
3117
3205
3209
3132
3132
3120
3296
3162
3147
3110
3210
3242
3142
3067
3193
3128
3155
3103
3234
3404
3191
```

*(time in microseconds)

And here's my question - why first few sorts are taking more time than the others? I have ran this program many times and sometimes it's first 20-30 of them, sometimes less, but ALWAYS at least the first one is taking significantly more time.
I believe it has something to do with the dynamic memory allocation in function merge1, but I really don't know what exactly.

edit: when I change the outer 'for' function in main so that it iterates twice, with array sizes of 2^14 and 2^18, the merge sort still takes longer for first iterations in array 2^14 but that is not the case for the 2^18 array (execution times here are uniform)

Comment: uhhmm... I don't C++, but did you have to iterate that many times? it makes the question strange to read... and dear lord the amount of code... is it all required for the question? or are you just looking for someone to debug your whole program, because you can't do that on stackoverflow...

Comment: I did have to iterate that many times to show exactly what the problem is. To show that the execution time decreases, but down to some point.
And yes, all the code is required for the question, because I don't know where the problem is. Do you?

Comment: no, but im good at spotting questions that probably won't get answered (a lot of code). I don't do C++

Comment: @damaxcontent As I've mentioned in the question, my gut tells me that the problem is in dynamic memory allocation in function merge1() and I could put only this code, but I'm afraid that I would only get answers like "you're probably measuring time in a wrong way, show whole code", etc.

Comment: well, put the simple code in here, and hide the complex code in a stackexchange snippet. Not exactly the way you're supposed to use it, but formatting is key.

Comment: The problem is merge1() takes most of the space, and it is used in the second largest function, which is... inside nested loop. It's all connected and hiding parts of it wouldn't help imho.
Now look, I'm not looking for someone to debugg my whole program as you suspected. I just want to know what is the cause of this behaviour, I wrote this entire code with a sole purpose of getting that answer.

Comment: Related: [Why is the performance of a running program getting better over time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517268/why-is-the-performance-of-a-running-program-getting-better-over-time)

Comment: @sergej That can actually be it - dynamic frequency scaling. Thank you very much, now I'm certain that all my today's measurements were incorrect :|